# Is NTLM and LM public algorithm?

Tags: security, ntlm

Is the NTLM and LM public algorithm? 
XP uses LM and Vista uses NTLM for password, is that right? Which algorithm is used by Windows7

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft has recently released documentation for the whole family of algorithms ([see this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc236621%28v=prot.13%29.aspx)) even though several people had already done an excellent job at reverse engineering them (see [Eric Glass' work here](http://davenport.sourceforge.net/ntlm.html)).

All Windows versions around today support LM and NTLM. What changes is the default value for the minimum version they accept during negotiation (as a client or as the server). To say, Window 7 does not accept to act as a NTLMv1 client anymore out of the box, only NTLMv2. You must really dig into the registry to allow client NTLMv1, even though that is a **totally bad** idea.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the algorithms have been *officially* published, but the way [LM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LM_hash) and [NTLM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTLM) hashes are computed is available on wikipedia.